# How can I use a UIImage as a pattern in Swift?

Tags: swift, xcode, uiimage

Within my GameScene I'd like to create a metal grating pattern. I have the image loaded, and the myPattern line is there just to make sure the image loads, which it does. However what I do get is just a black image.

I should add that if I set to any other SKColor, that does work. So am not sure what I'm doing wrong. Also, am not using Storyboard (other than LaunchScreen).

```
override func didMove(to view: SKView){

super.didMove(to: view)
var myPattern = UIImage(named: "metal.png")
self.backgroundColor = UIColor(patternImage: UIImage(named: "metal.png")!)


physicsWorld.contactDelegate = self
self.isHidden = true
self.isUserInteractionEnabled = false
tapRec.addTarget(self, action:#selector(WheelScene.tappedView(_:) ))
tapRec.numberOfTouchesRequired = 1
tapRec.numberOfTapsRequired = 1
self.view!.addGestureRecognizer(tapRec)
self.isHidden = false

let swipeUp = UISwipeGestureRecognizer()
let swipeDown = UISwipeGestureRecognizer()
let swipeLeft = UISwipeGestureRecognizer()
let swipeRight = UISwipeGestureRecognizer()

swipeUp.direction = .up
swipeDown.direction = .down
swipeLeft.direction = .left
swipeRight.direction = .right

view.addGestureRecognizer(swipeUp)
view.addGestureRecognizer(swipeDown)
view.addGestureRecognizer(swipeLeft)
view.addGestureRecognizer(swipeRight)

swipeUp.addTarget(self, action: #selector(Swipe(sender:)))
swipeDown.addTarget(self, action: #selector(Swipe(sender:)))
swipeLeft.addTarget(self, action: #selector(Swipe(sender:)))
swipeRight.addTarget(self, action: #selector(Swipe(sender:)))

let iSize = calcIconSize(sceneFrame: wheelScene!)

createPath(iSize: iSize)
createIcons(iSize: iSize)
```

}

Comment: See https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/21251?answerId=70218022#70218022

Comment: @matt   Saw you were right, but can't find how to create an .fsh file from an image.